# Does feather falling out of a flying creature's space provoke an attack of opportunity?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack, falling

Would feather falling out of a flying creature's space provoke an attack of opportunity?

The scenario: As you are feather falling, a flying creature flies and attacks you; you then are forced to fall out of his combat range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, neither Falling nor casting Feather Fall provokes an attack of opportunity.

Attacks of Opportunity are provoked by actions taken in combat. Falling is not an action, it is just what normally happens to your character when you are not supported by a floor.

> An enemy that **takes certain actions** while in a threatened square provokes an attack of opportunity from you.

Casting Feather Fall also does not provoke an Attack of Opportunity because it is a spell cast as an Immediate Action. Immediate Action spells do not provoke Attacks of Opportunity. The Core Rulebook explicitly states Feather Fall as the example of an Immediate Action spell not provoking.

> Table 8–2: Actions in Combat [Whether or not they provoke]
>
> *Cast feather fall*: **No**

Comment: Interesting that you've focused on the 'taking action' part here...only as line or two down, the rules say that moving out of a threatened square generally provokes, without talking about taking an action. I'm still not convinced an action is required. What about if a character steps off a cliff, and then falls past an enemy? Although an action was taken to step off, the fall itself is not an action...shouldn't it provoke, though?

Comment: One of the biggest evidences to this being the intended ruling is that most mechanical forms of forcing involuntary movement on a creature remind the player that they do not cause the creature to provoke attacks of opportunity. Only Greater versions of the Combat Maneuver induce AoOs as part of their benefit. So if every basic form of forced movement outlined in the Core Rulebook does not provoke, why would falling?

Comment: Also, losing 10 ft. of altitude when damaged while Flying doesn't provoke an AoO. Yet another example. I think the rule as written and the table of examples is clear enough, here.